Cloning 128GB SD card - getting 'kernel panic - not syncing' when booting using new card
I have used the SD card copier on my raspberry pi to clone the content of the current 128GB SD card onto a new 128GB SD card for backup purposes.
But when I tried to boot from the new card, I am getting 'Kernel panic -  not syncing: No working init found' error. Screen shot attached.

Then I tried the repair function:

sudo fsck /dev/sda1


sudo fsck /dev/sda2

There were a few 'Input/output error while getting next inode' messages, so I chose the recommended rewrite/clear options.
After that was all done, I tried to boot again using the new card, the booting error persisted.
I had a look at the cmdline.txt on both the old and new card, they were the same.
The alternative copy method has also been tried:

sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0p1 of=/dev/sda1 bs=4M status=progress

New card would not boot at all.
I have used another brand new 128GB SD card, did the copy again, got the exactly same error message when booting.
Additional information: initially, I used a 32GB SD card, then I cloned it on to a 128GB SD card. There were some issues, and I had to do some adjustment to the memory through raspi-config. Eventually I was able to use the 128GB card on rPi and use the 32GB card as backup.

I am aware of that, always 'sudo umount' before carrying out such operations.

An easy to clone a new 128G SD card to another 128G SD card would be to power off the Pi,  take out the boot 128G SD card and put your backup 32G card in micro sd slot. Power up, put your booted 128G SD card in a card reader, and plug it in a usb port. run the command lsblk and see your 32G boot card mmcblk0 and boot_able 128G card sda. Now put your new card in a card holder and plug it in an different usb port. run the lsblk cammand again and see the addition 128G card sdb. the sda and sdb will have mounted partitions. Run the command sudo umount /dev/sd[ab]*. Now you can run the dd command,sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=4M status=progress.
The cons will be both 128G SD cards will have the same PARTUUID. If both cards are in the same Pi, you might be booting one card and running on the other card, not good for updates.

I have not tried your method, but I have tried 'dd' using the original 128GB SD card in rPi and the new one plugged in using USB slot, after umount  mmcblk0 and sda  (/dev/mmcblk0p1 & /dev/sda1 in my case). The new card did not boot at all (black screen).

The Pi has a boot partition and a root partition. The boot partition is first on the card (/dev/mmcblk0p1 or /dev/sda1. The boot partition determines which options, which kernel and which root to boot. The root partition has all the file systems ( bin, home, etc, usr, ...). I am glad that you got it working.

Your new SD Card is faulty/counterfeit.
You could try the SD Card Formatter and perform a full format (which takes quite a while - often > 15minutes, depending on size)

I have bought the Sandisk from a large chain store in Australia, here is a link to the said card: https://www.bunnings.com.au/sandisk-128gb-ultra-micro-sdhc-120mb-s-class-10-uhs-i-micro-sd-card_p0404128, the chance of it being faulty/counterfeit is possible, but very small. I have also performed various disk operations on mac and rPi without any problems.

If you are getting I/O error something is wrong, either the card or whatever hardware you are using to write it.

I used another 128GB SD card, did the cloning, same issue. So, now I am certain the problem is not the SD card.

I used raspberry pi for the writing, but I also use it for running machine learning programs, for control servos, for camera, for running large stepper motors, for transmitting image from camera onto remote server, and for control actuators on  rPi from that remote server - never had a problem with it.

I am using rPi 4B and Accessories->SD Card Copier that comes with the raspbian to copy the SD card that's already in the rPi onto a SD card that is in a card reader plugged in a USB slot.

How else do you do your whole system backup?

This has long departed from a Pi question; I backup over my network. Thousands use SD Copier (as do I) but it depends on reliable hardware; previous reported errors have been hardware problems. If you can't accept this and test your hardware (which you have not detailed) further discussion is futile.

Anyways, I have able to clone the 128GB card onto another 128GB SD card, but I was not able to get it done directly with rasbperry pi's SD Card Copier application.
Instead, I have utilised Linux's 'dd' functionality on my Macbook.
To backup:

diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk4
sudo dd if=/dev/disk4 of=/Users/Telkitty/Desktop/raspbian_backup.img

To write to the new SD card:

diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk4
sudo dd if=/dev/disk4 of=/Users/Telkitty/Desktop/raspbian_backup.img
status=progress

Although they were both /dev/disk4, but it was the original SD card in the SD card slot the first time, and the destination SD card in the slot the second time round.
It took me 7-8 hours for the  whole process, but I am finally able to run the system using the new SD card in my Raspberry Pi and store the original card as backup.
